# How to extract a specific model from collection,and set id model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

Goodmorning,i'm a bit confused about a specific id that a model has got and the id that it's has in parse.com because my collection is linked to parse.com.

If i want to get a specific model from my collection how can i do?

An example,my collection is this:

```
          var Proposte = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model:Proposta,

    url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte',

    });

        return Proposte;
```

and my model is this:

```
       var Proposta = Backbone.Model.extend({
       url:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte",
       ...
```

If i want to get a specific model from my collection how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

have a try at this:

```
var item = Proposte.findWhere({'url':"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte"});
```

hare is the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere)

**Edit:**

The code above gives you the first matched model of the collection.
If you want to get multiple models that matches the specific attributes of a model, just use [where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where)

Answer (score 0):

**General case:**

***Define `idAttribute` for your Model/Collection:***

```
var Proposta = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'name',

});

var Proposte = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Proposta,
    url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte'
});


// Done here with static data just for illustration
var collection = new Proposte([{name: 'aaa'}, {name: 'bbb'}]);
```

***Use the defined attribute to retrieve Models from collection:***

```
console.log(collection.get('aaa'));
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjBEU/)

**`URL`, of course, can also be that attribute (just in case):**

```
var Proposta = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'url'
});
var Proposte = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Proposta,
    url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte',
});

var collection = new Proposte([{url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte/1'}, {url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte/2'}]);

console.log(collection.get('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Proposte/2'));
```

Comment: If i set idAttribute to: objectId that is the same value of column parse.com does it match? i've tried with: var collection=new Proposte(); and collection.get("45g24y"); but don't works

Comment: I am not sure what `objectId` is, but think of it in this way. You are populating your collection with objects that are normally homogeneous, which means that they have **some** attribute that distinguishes one from the other. I am not sure what `parse.com` does. Can you show an example of item in the collection? Simple `console.log` should do (as long as the data is not sensitive).

Comment: i can fetch and show you a collection by parse but model i can't